# Проблема с CoordinatorLayout внутри DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Есть DrawerLayout

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBgPages"
tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/view_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout="@layout/no_net" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorBgPages"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

В одном из фрагментов есть layout с такой разметкой

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBgPages"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
tools:context=".fragments.NewsDetail">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_news_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgPages"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CustomTitleCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorBgPages"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@color/opacityBg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/new_roman_italic_bold"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_news_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TitleText" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <include layout="@layout/content_news_detail" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

@layout/content_news_detail

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_news_detail"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view_news_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Изначально отображается нормально

[image: Изначально отображается нормально]

Но при скролле вверх появляется отступ внизу. Как от него избавиться?

[image: Вот такой отступ]

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался с проблемой. Удалил из @layout/content_news_detail значение android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"